# call a function after previous function is complete and after the value get updated in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core

I have  three cascaded drop down select list 1. Depot 2. Department 3. Employee.
When I select the Depot , related Department would be listed and then Employee dropdown filled with related record. The code for Department and Employee dropdown, are called from common js file for the global use in the module.

In the html page I am calling another function to list Employee Salary called EmpSalary() in every change of  Employee dropdown. When I change Depot, then Department  and Employee dropdown would be refreshed and updated with related values. But the empid in EmpSalary() is always being showed with old Empid previously selected until the EmpId being selected from Employee Dropdown .
I am trying to get  if there is any change in Depot , Department value, the Empid  is always being showed with  previously I selected in the function SalaryView() . Because the SalaryView() is called before the completion of FllUserEmployeeSelect(). I cannot make any change in code in the dropdown from site.js. It is used in other html pages also.  So how can I call SalaryView() after the completion of FllUserEmployeeSelect()

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdownEmployee').change(function(e) {
      SalaryView();
    }).change();
  })

function SalaryView() {

  var empid = $('#dropdownEmployee').val();
  alert(empid);
};

// dropdown code calling from site.js file
function FillUserLocationSelect() {
  var depotId = $("#dropdownDepot").val();
  var locationId = $("#dropdownDepartment").val();
  var url = "/User/GetLocationSelectListByDepot";
  $.getJSON(url, {
    depotNo: depotId
  }, function(data) {
    var item = "";
    $("#dropdownDepartment").empty();
    $("#dropdownEmployee").empty();
    var Names = document.getElementById('dropdownDepartment');
    $.each(data, function(i) {
      opt = document.createElement('option');
      Names.options.add(opt);
      opt.text = data[i].text;
      opt.value = data[i].value;
      if (data[i].selected) {
        opt.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
      }
    });
    FillUserEmployeeSelect();
  });
}

function FillUserEmployeeSelect() {
  var depotId = $("#dropdownDepot").val();
  var locationId = $("#dropdownDepartment").val();
  var url = "/User/GetEmployeeSelectList";
  $.getJSON(url, {
    depotNo: depotId,
    departmentId: locationId
  }, function(data) {
    var item = "";
    $("#dropdownEmployee").empty();
    var Names = document.getElementById('dropdownEmployee');
    $.each(data, function(i) {
      opt = document.createElement('option');
      Names.options.add(opt);
      opt.text = data[i].text;
      opt.value = data[i].value;
      if (data[i].selected) {
        opt.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
      }

    });

  });
} <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Depot</label>
      <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <select id="dropdownDepot" class="form-control" asp-for="DepotNo" asp-items="@ViewBag.UserDepots" data-role="select" onchange="FillUserLocationSelect()"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Department</label>
      <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <select id="dropdownDepartment" class="form-control" asp-for="DepartmentID" asp-items="@ViewBag.UserDepartments" data-role="select" onchange="FillUserEmployeeSelect();"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Employee</label>
      <div class="controls col-sm-9">
        <select id="dropdownEmployee" class="form-control" asp-for="EmployeeID" asp-items="@ViewBag.Employees" data-role="select"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `So how can I call SalaryView() after the completion of FllUserEmployeeSelect()`Why not call `SalaryView` in `FillUserEmployeeSelect` like what you did in `FillUserLocationSelect`?

Comment: I cannot call SalaryView  from FillUserEmployeeSelect   since  FillUserEmployeeSelect() is being used in different html. Some html doesnot need SalaryView() , . Some different module html  is also using that function to get Employee dropdown